# webdriver: Upload file in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, upload, webdriver

Any idea about how to upload a file in IE?
It's not the first time I have such problem but I always solved it by setting the hidden input txt to visible

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) SelTestCase.driver;
WebElement element=SelTestCase.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';"
```

But this time i dont see any hidden style within the input so really have to idea how to this. Firefox and chrome works fine, I just send the path but IE warn element is not visible

Any idea ?

```
<div class="btn btn-primary ib-fileupload">
    <span>Upload File</span>
    <input id="channel-image-upload" class="upload pristine" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the *attribute* directly and clicking the upload(or whatever to fire that action). And, make sure you only try one of the following file types since that's all the allowed

> .jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.png

```
String filePath = "the filepath with extension";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('channel-image-upload').setAttribute('value', '"+filePath+"');");
driver.findElement(By.id("id of the button that uploads the file")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the input may also be out of page bounds. You can set the style attribute and then just type in the input as normal.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) SelTestCase.driver;
WebElement element=SelTestCase.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
//set the style
String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('style','position: absolute; opacity: 0;');"
```